# Possibility of a Dark Star

Tags: gravity, visible-light, stars

I think it was a very early notion, pre-black holes, that there may exist a star that was so massive, all of its outgoing light would return to its source.

Is this actually possible? Is there an upper limit to the size of stars, because of physical processes, which would stop this?

Comment: I think the very fact that the light wouldn't leave the source classifies the above star as a black hole?

Comment: I think what you are asking is whether some other physical processes inhibit the formation of a black hole in the first place. Is that correct?

Comment: I have asked this making a definition between a point mass and somethung with volume. @Hritik Narayan you are correct!

Comment: Laura Mersini-Houghton has claimed that the back-reaction of Hawking radiation will create a bouncing star scenario. She plans to drop some assumptions she made in her first paper and report the findings later. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269314006686

Comment: Interesting; I'd have thought HR would be negligible when compared to the infalling mass of a collapsing star.

Comment: Mersini-Houghton writes English verbiage about physics more beautifully than anyone, but her work has, since 2012, been marred by a rant against Poincare recurrence and in favor of QM's Many Worlds Interpretation.  (I've been unable to see just why the absence of one might render the other more plausible:  At least when she refrains from formalism--which seems very supportive of Poincare--it just seems like a preference for variety over repetition.)

Comment: @KieranHunt -I saw your point at first, and then I remembered that Nobel winner Penrose's Conformal Cyclic Cosmology has all matter periodically evaporating into radiation:  The time scales involved are phenomenally long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape velocity is given by: $v_e = \sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r}}$.  Setting $v_e$ to $c$, the speed of light, and rearranging, we obtain $r = \frac{2GM}{c^2}$, which is also the expression for [Schwarzschild radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius) of a non-rotating black hole.

Therefore any object with such a property would eventually collapse to a black hole (if not already one). The same is true for a rotating star, although the maths is a little harder.

Comment: You cant apply Newtonian mechanics here.ofcourse both general relativity and Newtonian mechanics by coincidence gives same result.

Comment: Of course, but it illustrates the point just as well, without having to spell out the (more complicated) derivation via the Schwarzschild metric.

Comment: @KieranHunt I moved the comment to the main question.

Comment: Stars lacking (as a result of interactions with black holes and other stars) at least some faint residual rotation might be so rare as to be entirely lacking in our currently observable region.